# Record-triggered flow

Tags: visual-workflow, tasks, flow-builder

I have to make a flow that executes when a Task is updated.

When a task is updated, I have to check that the CallDisposition field has the value "Confirm Booking".

After that it has to search for Tasks with all of the following:

- the same originNumer
- a `CallDisposition` value that is "Booking Petition"
- `confirmation_id` and `confirmation_date` are empty.

This will return a list of Tasks which are ordered by `createdDate` DESC.

For each element of the list, if `createdDate <= than the createdDate` of the task which started the flow, the fields `BookingPetitionDate` is filled with `createdDate` of the element of the list and `Bookingpetition_id` is filled with the id of the task from the list. These fields are updated from the task that started the flow.
It also updates the fields `ConfirmBookingDate` and `ConfirmBookingId` with the fields from the task which started the flow.

I have made the flow and when I create a booking petition and a confirm booking tasks, it only fills the fields on the second one. The Booking petition fields stays empty.

Here you have a picture of the whole flow, the settings of the last getRecords, and the two tasks after the flow has been executed. The first one is the petition and the second one the confirmation.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question and mention what have you tried and where exactly you are struck with flow diagram .

Comment: i've added some pictures to show what's missing

Comment: you have an Update element inside an iteration - this is bad practice and will lead to governor limits being breached. Instead, build up a record collection variable and then use it in an Update element after then end of the loop

Comment: Now i have completely changed the flow. The first two before stay the same, the assignment and the getRecords. Now i loop through that list and have inside a decision box to see if the date of the petitions are earlier than the confirmation record. If it's true, i assign values to the confirmation variables(date and id) and add the records to a collection. Also i assign values to the petition fields form the triggering record. Outside the loop i update the collection and the record which triggered the flow.